# Are ESB still worth as communication layer? Which ones?

Tags: web-services, google-apps, sql-server, rest, apache

I need to develop a comunication layer between my application and customer's.
There are different data exchanges and I'm looking for some solutions. I don't know much about Enterprise Service Bus application, are they worth? Do you know any?

My application environment is made mainly of `SSIS`, `SQL Server`, `Apache`, all on premis.

I need to communicate with customer's enviroments in different ways:

- Move files through

  - `Google Cloud Storage`;
  - `Samba`;
  - `SFTP`;
- Calling `REST API` with Google Oauth2 authentication;
- Expose a `REST API` with Google Oauth2 authentication.

For now, we are thinking about C# code, or Java code on Apache, but a middle layer solution like ESB or some other will be easier and more powerful.

Thanks for your adivices.

Comment: Are you just pulling the data from the customer or are you also pushing the data to the customer?

Comment: Both directions. *Pushing*: put files on bucket, expose REST service. *Pulling*: get files, consume REST service. I need also read/write to DBMS but for this I have also more traditional solution, so DBMS it's not mandatory for ESB solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, I don't have enough details.

As you are using `SFTP`, `Samba` and `Google Cloud Storage` it seems to me that you are moving .CSV and probably ingesting them through `SSIS`.

Then you are also using `REST API` to push and pull data.

You are doing it right, you are using .CSV for legacy stuff and REST API for more modern stuff.

If you want to modernize you might want to pass everything to REST API and that will be your ESB communication layer. It seems like you are already doing it.

You might just need to consolidate that.

Otherwise you can use [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) or [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/).

Comment: Almost like. I wish to use a ESB application as middle layer, to manage all REST services and files transmissions in the same point. *As it is now* every data transfert is stand alone coding, and they are made in different ways (see SISS, C#, …). But it will be complicate and I want to reorganize it sooner.

Comment: "I don't know, I don't have enough details." <- Would you mind listing the details that would help you write a more helping answer? Thanks! :-)

Comment: How can I list more details if I don't have details?

Comment: Single files via SFTP/SAMBA/GCS and REST APIs are the current ways for data transfert, between a) windows server (with SSIS/SQL Server) and b) other servers. I'm asking if there is any ESB application that could help me in managing all files/REST stuff, instead of developing every single data trasfert. I mean, i.e., an application that can link to google, samba, sftp, REST, in order to save SSIS from coding for all different protocols.

Comment: Well, there are things like Zapier or PowerAutomate, they are low code programming (like an SSIS with an easier GUI) and they can connect to nearly everything. But this will not save you from a no-code solution or a solution that you have to maintain.

Comment: This can be a good answer. "code with one tool" or "recode only one tool in case of change" can be better that "change every code everytime". It's all about how are Zapier or PowerAutomate or whatever. My question was focused about which tool is, nowadays, worth  the effort.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. But before screaming victory check those solutions. One size fits all rarely works

Comment: Oh no, I don't. Please update your answer to make it complete, for the use of other readers

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved this yet?

It seems like you're looking for something like [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/).

You write integrations with Camel DSL, very powerful.

Comment: Pleaae don't ask a question inside an answer.